# Delphi TJSONArray.ToBytes Access violation - Is it

Tags: json, delphi

The problem is at the TJSONArray.ToBytes call at the end. The target TBytes repository exists. Have I set the size incorrectly using SizeOf? TJSONArray.Count must surely give only the number of objects in the JSON array. What did I miss? I tried an offset of 1 for the second argument to ToBytes, but it did not work and I do not think that it is the correct index...

The code successfully reads JSON from a file into iCJSONCallData (a TJSONArray object).

```
  // Private variables in the class
    iCJSONAsStr          : string;
    iCJSONBytes          : TBytes;
    iCJSONAllSourceBytes : TBytes;
    iCJSONByteStream     : TBytesStream;
    iCCallData   : TStringList;
    iCJSONCallData  : TJSONArray;
    iCJSONCallSet   : TJSONValue;
    iCJSONParamData : TJSONArray;
.
.
.
    var
      vJSONCalls              : TJSONArray;
      vJSONCallElement        : TJSONObject;
      vJSONCallPair           : TJSONPair;
      vJSONCallEntry          : TJSONString;
      vJSONCallValue          : TJSONValue;
      vJSONCAllDataBytes : TBytes;
      vJSONCallPairEnumerator : TJSONPairEnumerator;
      vJSONCallList           : TStringList;
      vJSONCallDesc           : string;
      vPathCount              : integer;
      vCount : integer;
      vCurrentFileName        : string;


    begin

       if iCJSONByteStream = nil then
        iCJSONByteStream := TBytesStream.Create;

      if vJSONCallList = nil then
        vJSONCallList := TStringList.Create;

      for vCurrentFileName in uCRPCDataFileNames do 
      begin

        iCJSONBytes := TFile.ReadAllBytes(vCurrentFileName);
        iCJSONAsStr := TFile.ReadAllText(vCurrentFileName);

        if iCCallData = nil then
          iCCallData := TStringList.Create;
        if iCJSONCallData = nil then
          iCJSONCallData := TJSONArray.Create();
        if iCJSONCallSet = nil then
          iCJSONCallSet := TJSONValue.Create;

        iCJSONCallSet := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(iCJSONBytes , 0);

        if iCJSONCallSet <> nil then
          try
            iCJSONCallData := iCJSONCallSet as TJSONArray;

            try
              for vJSONCallValue in iCJSONCallData do
              begin
                vJSONCallElement := vJSONCallValue as TJSONObject;
                vJSONCallPair    := vJSONCallElement.Get(uCCallKey); //uCCallKey is a string

                vJSONCallEntry := vJSONCallPair.JsonString;

                vJSONCallDesc := vJSONCallPair.JsonValue.ToString;

                iCCallData.Append(vJSONCallDesc);
              end;

            except
              on E : Exception do
              ShowMessage('Error ' + E.Message);
            end;

            SetLength(vJSONCAllDataBytes, SizeOf(iCJSONCallData));
            vCount := iCJSONCallData.ToBytes(vJSONCAllDataBytes, 0); //Access violation... <<<==

          finally


          end;
```

Comment: Your try/except is bogus. You swallow the error, and then carry on using the data, as if nothing happened. If you want some specific help with your error, show a complete program and provide the necessary input data.

Comment: Also the try/finally is just useless. In general if you only want to show the exception, simply do nothing. The application will show the exception and stops all code from the current call.

Comment: The try except and try finally should have been removed from the example. They were there to handle other things in the code that were removed. Sorry for the inconvenience. I know you hate me David and so I will expect negative criticism from you which I will ignore unless it actually helps with something.

Comment: I removed the try blocks. The problem went away. I put the offending lines of code inside the try except block and reintroduced it. The error stayed away. Inappropriate exception handling for that code as The Heff indicated, I think.

Comment: Would you rather we told you that you code was wonderful? How would that help?

Comment: The code is here because it is problematic, obviously. Would you rather I told you that a less than fully documented set of libraries and interfaces was wonderful? Sure I can go and read libraries and that is part of the job description. However, it is meant to be a RAD development platform, and if people are trying to develop something quickly they need not to have to waste too much time finding out via trial and error how some component or property works.

Comment: It seems strange that you describe constructive criticism that actually helps (you later said as much) as "negative". We all make mistakes. Whenever you post here expect people to point them out to you. Would you rather know about a mistake that you made, or continue in ignorance of it? I'm sorry that I tried to help you. It seems that you don't want to be helped.

Comment: I said that you were right above. Thanks for the help David.

Comment: That's my point. What you described as "negative" turned out to be the core of your problem. You ask a question, you get valuable help the leads you to a solution, and then you complain. You say I hate you. I don't. I've no idea who you are. And you tell me that you will ignore my advice. I'd say that you need to make this less personal and take comments at face value.

Comment: I don't know. Your first ever response to me (in a previous) was pretty needlessly negative. You do go on a bit... Perhaps you need to work on your people skills yourself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your use of `SizeOf()` is wrong. `iCJSONCallData` is an object, so `SizeOf(iCJSONCallData)` is effectively the same as `SizeOf(Pointer)`, which is 4 on 32bit and 8 on 64bit.

You need to use the [`TJSONArray.EstimatedByteSize()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.JSON.TJSONArray.EstimatedByteSize) method instead:

```
SetLength(vJSONCallDataBytes, iCJSONCallData.EstimatedByteSize);
vCount := iCJSONCallData.ToBytes(vJSONCallDataBytes, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks Remy. I will try that.
Tried it. Still getting the same error at the indicated point.
Must be something else. Thanks kindly anyway.

Comment: The info about the correct method for TJSONArray size is right of course. the problem was other stuff (see above).